# C++ sdl_mixer

Tags: sdl, c++

Здравствуйте, я недавно начал изучать sdl, вот идет разборка со звуком.Суть проблемы в том что я сделал ну совершенно все чтобы звук нормально воспроизводился, однако нет, чудим, звука нету.
Что я упустил?
P.S У меня наушники (но думаю это не проблема)

Вот код:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "SDL.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "SDL_mixer.h"

SDL_Event event;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{       
        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);//Video
        bool done = false;
        SDL_Window* window;
        SDL_Renderer* renderer;
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("GetShit",SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,700, 500,0);
        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 245, 255, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

        Mix_Init(MIX_INIT_MP3);//AUDIO
        Mix_OpenAudio(44100, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, -1, 1024);
        Mix_Music *pahomsong = NULL;
        pahomsong=Mix_LoadMUS("pahom.mp3");
        Mix_PlayMusic(pahomsong, -1);

while (!done)
{
  while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
      done=true;
      Mix_CloseAudio();
      Mix_Quit();
      SDL_Quit();
    }
  }
}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вообщем Solved, капец, 1 файл забыл поместить в папку проекта.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю проверять, загрузился ли трек или нет. В SDL есть функция - SDL_GetError().

Например:

```
if(!(pahomsong = Mix_LoadMUS("pahom.mp3"))) //Если что-то не так
  cout << SDL_GetError() << endl; //Вывести ошибку
```